# What's the etymology of English letter casing terminology?

Tags: etymology, history, capitalization

The popular consensus around the web (i.e., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case)) seems to be that "upper case" and "lower case" originate from typesetting convention of upper and lower drawers for letters, possibly preceded by the Latin terminology of majuscule and minuscule.

However, none of these references seem to be backed up properly, and frankly, I find the explanation tickling my urban legend senses - my suspicion is that this is an incomplete or even false etymology, but I can't find anything better.

Is there a more authoritative source that attests to whether or not this is a true etymology?

Comment: OED confirms that the capitals were in the printer's upper case, and the small letters in their lower case. Alas, it is subscription only.

Comment: @MattЭллен: I've got a subscription, if you want me to look it up, but I'd be surprised if this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @J.R. I have access, I just mean that it's difficult to cite OED.com because other people can't follow the link.

Comment: Ah! I see. [This](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=%22upper+case%22&searchmode=none) might suffice, then.  OED concurs, under the word *case* (meaning 9), but you'll just have to take our word for it.

Comment: I can vouch from personal experience from the times of hand compositing off wooden drawers and before computers became mainstream. (No I am no spirit from the lo..ng past! -- the time was just the '60s).

Comment: Well, Ben, there you have it: Etymonline, OED, and Kris.  Is that authoritative enough for you? :^)

Comment: So can I, @Kris. In fact I still have one of my father's [California cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Job_Case) downstairs.

Comment: @Colin Fine. Oh great! If I did, I'd never part with them. What was the year you saw them in use? And the year you first heard 'uppercase' in computers, Colin Fine?

Comment: @Kris: I remember composing with a stick in the early 60's. My parents had had a jobbing printing business before I was born, but probably about '60 or '61 the person they had passed the equipment on to died, and they got it back. They never ran it as a business after that, but my father used to do little jobs for friends and family, and I was compasing before I was 10. Don't know when I met "uppercase" in computers.

Comment: @Colin Fine Nostalgia! The 60s were the days of IBM 1620 series, PDP-11 and such mysterious wonders. Keyboard input came later, and well, the PC made it ubiquitous.

Comment: That seems reasonable; I think my initial hesitation stemmed from the fact that the origin of the terms necessarily implies that another set of terms must have been previously in use; i.e., what did the printers who first formalized the upper/lower English arrangement call the letters? Does the OED (or any other source) confirm the majuscule/minuscule terminology before the widespread use of upper/lower, and does it give a timeframe for popularization of the terms?

Comment: The OED cites "lower-case", in the modern sense from 1683. Its oldest citation for "minuscule" is 1703. I haven't found evidence for what words were used previously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The full OED explanation is that in printing a case is ‘The receptacle or frame in which the compositor has his types, divided into compartments for the various letters, figures, and spaces. In ordinary printing the compositor has two such cases before him on a slanting stand, the upper case containing the capitals, etc., the lower the small letters, ordinary spaces, etc.’

This is supported by four citations, the earliest dating from 1588.

Comment: There is new terminology now in these heady Unicode days.  *Titlecase* is by analogy with the other two, but there was never a special case for storing such things in a compositor’s set. Special sorts like a *Th* would go with the other ligatures in faces that supported such; there was no title case.